# Proguard, Minify, Jsoup and Stack Trace

Tags: android, jsoup, proguard, minify

OK, I have been working on this for a few days now, so I know what is the problem, what is the cause and what is the solution. What I need is a few simple technical details so that I can implement the solution.

I am getting an "Unfortunately Has Stopped" message in my release version that does not occur in the debug version. This happens both on my S4 mini and on the Samsung RTL devices. The debug version works on all of these devices plus on the Genymotion emulators. The error occurs using Jsoup when I tap my menu choice which activates Jsoup.connect.

The problem is most likely caused by ProGuard, in the minify process. And it most likely concerns Proguard minifying out some of the needed Jsoup library routines. The release program does run if I set minifyEnabled to false but I would prefer to un-apply minify just where necessary.

The solution is to disable the minify possibly for all of Jsoup as it is small anyway, but preferably just for the certain parts. I have read that with a stack trace I could identify which specific Jsoup modules need to be eliminated from minify rather than minifying the complete lib.

So I need to know a few simple, technical things ...

1. What is the syntax for the proguard statement to eliminate **org.jsoup.*** from being minified?
2. Which file is this statement to be added to, **proguard-android.txt** or **proguard-rules.pro**?
3. How do I initiate a stack trace? In particular I need to be able to do this while running a release version of the program. It must be simple but my searches have not turned up a step by step procedure for this.

It seems that these are very basic questions. Virtually every post on every forum or blog that i have read on these subjects assumes that you know these things. For the stack trace i need the detailed steps. Hope you can help.

EDIT:
OK, making a little progress. I found the -s or --stacktrace option and where to set it in the IDE. However I am lost about where to find the actual stacktrace when I run the program.

EDIT#2
Making better progress. Found this example **-keep class org.joda.time.** { ; }** so I substituted jsoup in place of joda, put it into the proguard-rules.pro file and my release build now runs :)

I would still like to get some assistance with the stacktrace. All I find in various blogs and forums is methods for remote stack trace of published apps. I would like to simply view the stacktrace in Android Studio.

***Mick***

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keeppackagenames org.jsoup.nodes
```

**Edit:**

You can also try this one:

```
-keep public class org.jsoup.** { public *; }
```

But no need to keep everything. `-keeppackagenames org.jsoup.nodes` is enough.